# PPT Quiz slides generation by linking MS-PowerPoint with MS-Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint

I am using MS-Office 2013. There is a quiz template in MS PowerPoint as a PPT. I created question bank in MS-Excel. Now, I would like to link this (excel) file with PowerPoint to automatically generate quiz slides.

I would like to use it in a quiz competition in the class to show them questions on Projector. 
Any idea to generate PPT quiz of 200 questions/slides with less time. Otherwise I have to copy and past each question/answer.

Comment: Are you showing a PPT presentation as the quiz? But you prefer to link the questions from an Excel Workbook? `Any idea to generate projector based quiz of 200 questions with less time.` Can you reword this question, I have not idea what this means. Projector, 200, less time?

Comment: Yes, PPT presentation as a quiz. I need to copy/past each question from excel to ppt. I am searching VBA code or any shortcut way to do it.

Comment: I think this should server you. Then from there you'd made your questions in Excel, then you could copy and paste the inserted Excel Sheets into each new slide and then manipulate the Cell Reference in the format provided. Just mark the green check mark if it works out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to use Excel, to link Text to a PowerPoint Presentation:

1. Create your PPT. In this example I named it P1.pptx
2. Create your questions in Excel. In this example I named it Book1.xlsx
3. On the slide. Insert Tab → Table → Excel SpreadSheet
4. Double click a cell on the inserted Sheet.

**Use this format**: `=TEXT([Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!A1,1)`

**Note**: The [Book1.xlsx] is local to the P1.pptx. Local means that it's in the same folder/directory.

---

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]